# dereference variable address through null structure pointer, no segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, null, segmentation-fault, dereference

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
}stTemp_t;

int main()
{
stTemp_t *pstTemp = NULL;
int *p = &(pstTemp->a);       // <<----- supposedly de-ref NULL pointer

return 0;
}
```

The instruction pointed above, i thought should've caused a segmentation fault which it does not. I tried omitting the default compiler optimization by using "gcc -O0".

Naturally enough, if I replace that with `int i = pstTemp->a`, I get a seg-fault. I tried to run the above program throgh gdb to figure out what is going on & following is my observation -

```
(gdb) p pstTemp
$2 = (stTemp_t *) 0x0
(gdb) p pstTemp->a
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb) p &(pstTemp->a)
$3 = (int *) 0x0
```

here in `$3`, we can see that when i try to print `&(pstTemp->a)`, it seems to be interpreted as an address hence being equivalent to `int *p = NULL`.

However my doubt is, shouldn't the statement `(pstTemp->a)` get evaluated before the & takes effect & cause a seg-fault anyways?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, it's not even the act of **dereferencing** the null pointer that's causing undefined behavior in your code.

When an address-of (`&`) and a dereference (`*` or `->`) operation follow each other immediately, then they cancel each other and collapse into **pointer arithmetic.** Thus, the expression `&pstTemp->a` yields the address of `a`.

However, **performing pointer arithmetic on a NULL pointer is undefined behavior.** Since no actual dereferencing done (and the behavior is undefined anyways), it seems the compiler just didn't emit any apparently harmful code that would caused a segmentation fault.

Don't expect undefined behavior to result in any particular error. It's called **undefined** and not "guaranteed crash" *for a reason.*

Comment: Can you please point me to the related chapter in the standard, preferably C11? I see nothing in §6.5.2.3,

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'm searching for the relevant part.

Comment: Yes, please let me know. Specifically, I'm interested in `they cancel each other and collapse into pointer arithmetic` part. I can see the example from footnote (102) in §6.5.3.2, but that is not quite the same. I'm interested. Is this indeed a pure C thing or something compiler specific?

Comment: @SouravGhosh that's not the same order, but given that "A postfix expression followed by the `->` operator and an identifier designates a member of a structure or union object" (6.5.2.3) and "if it [the operand of `*`] points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the
object", and a member of a structure or union must be an object (or a bitfield, which doesn't count here since its address cannot be taken), this means that the other direction is also true: `&foo->bar` is the same as `&(*foo).bar`, and…

Comment: @SouravGhosh for `&` followed by `*`, the standard already says "If the operand is the result of a unary * operator, neither that operator nor the & operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted" (6.5.3.2).

Answer (score 4):

It's undefined behaviour.

It doesn't crash here, because there is no actual dereferencement, we only take the *address* of `(pstTemp->b)` which is actually the offset of the `b` field (most likely 4, depending on the size of `int` and the compiler).

Try this:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} stTemp_t;

int main()
{
  stTemp_t *pstTemp = NULL;
  int *p = &(pstTemp->b);

  printf ("%p", p);
  return 0;
}
```

Te output will most likely be:

```
00000004
```

But

```
   printf ("%d", pstTemp->b);
```

will most likely crash.